# Nhibernate, HQL left join order by right table column

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to make a left join, but order by a column in the right table using hql?

For example we have these classes in the domain:

```
public class SomeDocument
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentPart Part1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentPart Part2 { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentPart
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Part1 and Part2 properties are nullable.

SQL:

```sql
create table SomeDocument
  (
    Id number(*, 0) not null,
    DocumentPart1_ID NUMBER,
    DocumentPart2_ID NUMBER
  );

create table DocumentPart
  (
    Id number(*, 0) not null,
    Content nvarchar2(250) not null
  );
```

Mapping:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Testapp.domain" namespace="Testapp.domain.model">
  <class name='SomeDocument' table='SomeDocument' lazy="false">
    <many-to-one name='Part1' class="Testapp.domain.model.DocumentPart, Testapp.domain" lazy="false" column='DocumentPart1_ID' cascade="save-update" />
    <many-to-one name='Part1' class="Testapp.domain.model.DocumentPart, Testapp.domain" lazy="false" column='DocumentPart2_ID' cascade="save-update" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Testapp.domain" namespace="Testapp.domain.model">
  <class name='DocumentPart' table='DocumentPart' lazy="false">
    <property name='Content' column='Content' not-null="true"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and now if I try to order `SomeDocuments` by `Part1.Content`:

```
UnitOfWork.CurrentSession
          .CreateQuery("from SomeDocument doc order by doc.Part1.Content")
          .List<SomeDocument>();
```

I will get only rows where `DocumentPart1_ID` is not null. NHibernate will generate SQL like this:

```sql
select * from 
SomeDocument doc, 
DocumentPart docPart,
where doc.DocumentPart1_ID = docPart.Id
order by docPart.Content
```

but what I want is something like this:

```sql
select * from 
SomeDocument doc
left join DocumentPart docPart on doc.DocumentPart1_ID = docPart.Id
order by docPart.Content
```

My database is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly specify to nhibernate that you want a left join in the query.

```
select doc from SomeDocument doc left join doc.Part1 part order by part.Content
```

If you leave out the `select doc` from the query, NHibernate will select all the entities, in this case it would be equivalent to writing `select doc, part`. This would create a result set of type `object[]` that represents a tuple of `SomeDocument, DocumentPart`.

Comment: ty Sir. adding "select doc" to query string fixed the problem.

Comment: seriously, I have to manually write out joins every time?? there's no way to configure this in the mappings? Yikes.

Comment: Normally you could configure it to use an eager left join, but in this query I'm unsure what the result would be, since `a.b.c` tends to create an inner join from a to b. Also you'll probably get duplicates in the result if you don't use something like Transformers.DistinctRootEntity